# Trace function and linear relations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, trace

The setup: Let $n \equiv 0$ mod $3$ and consider the trace function 
$$\text{Tr}\,_{\mathbb{F}_{3^n}/\mathbb{F}_{3^{n/3}}}(\alpha)=\alpha+\alpha^{3^{n/3}}+\alpha^{3^{2n/3}}$$ 
which is a surjective linear map from $\mathbb{F}_{3^n}$ to $\mathbb{F}_{3^{n/3}}$. Clearly, $\text{ker}\,(\text{Tr})$ has dimension $2n/3$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$.

---

My question: What (if anything) can we say about elements in the kernel of the trace function? For example, must there necessarily exist some element $\beta \in \mathbb{F}_{3^n}$ not contained within any intermediate fields such that $\text{Tr}\,(\beta)=0$? Furthermore, if we have some nontrivial linear relation of the form $\beta+\beta^{3^k}+\beta^{3^m}=0$ with $0 < k,m < n$, does this give us any additional information about what $\text{Tr}\,(\beta)$ might be?

---

Attempts: Perhaps this is a clever application of additive Hilbert's theorem 90 (below)?

> Given a finite cyclic extension $K$ over $F$ with Galois group $\langle \sigma \rangle$ and an element $\beta \in K$, $\text{Tr}\,_{K/F}(\beta)=0$ if and only if $\beta=\alpha-\sigma(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in K$.

I also wonder if there is some dimensional argument that shows that the size of all subfields of $\mathbb{F}_{3^n}$ must always be smaller than $\text{ker}\,(\text{Tr})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the kernel of the (relative) trace map is a 2-dimensional vector space over the intermediate field $K=\Bbb{F}_{3^{n/3}}$. This is because that trace is $K$-linear. Therefore the kernel, indeed, has cardinality $3^{2n/3}$. Because we are in characteristic three $K$ is itself contained in the kernel.

The first question can be answered in the affirmative by a counting argument.
The subfield $\Bbb{F}_3(\beta)$ fails to be the entire field $L=\Bbb{F}_{3^n}$ if and only if $\beta$ belongs to one of the proper subfields of $L$. Such subfields have $3^d$ elements for some $d\mid n$, and there is exactly one such subfield of each cardinality. As the largest possible factor $d=n/2$ (when $n$ happens to be even), the union of proper subfields has at most
$$
\sum_{d\mid n, d<n}3^d\le\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}3^k=\frac{3^{1+n/2}-1}{3-1}
$$
elements. It is easy to see that this is $<3^{2n/3}$, so there must exist an element $\beta$ such that $\mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(\beta)=0$ and $\beta$ is not an element of any proper subfield of $L$.

If we know that
$$
\beta+\beta^{3^k}+\beta^{3^m}=0,\qquad(*)
$$
then because $Gal(L/\Bbb{F}_3)$ is cyclic generated by the Frobenius, we can deduce that 
$$
\mathrm{Tr}_{L/K}(\beta+\beta^{3^k}+\beta^{3^m})=0
$$
as well.

We can actually say a bit more about the set of solutions of $(*)$ in $L$.
Not sure you find this interesting, but I do, so I will explain it anyway.
So let
$$
N=\{\beta\in L\mid \beta+\beta^{3^k}+\beta^{3^m}=0\}.
$$
We already saw that $N$ is a vector space over the prime field, and that it is stable under the action of Frobenius automorphism.

Furthermore, the theory of linearized polynomials (see Lidl & Niederreiter or Goss's book *Arithmetic in Function Fields* or Rosen's book *Number Theory in Function Fields* or ...) tells us that if we calculate the greatest common divisor
$$
d(\tau)=\gcd(\tau^n-1,\tau^m+\tau^k+1)
$$
in the polynomial ring $\Bbb{F}_3[\tau]$, and denote $r=\deg d(\tau)$, then

- $|N|=3^r$, and
- If $d(\tau)=\sum_{i=0}^rd_i\tau^i$ with $d_i\in\Bbb{F}_3$, then
  $$
  N=\{z\in\overline{L}\mid \sum_{i=0}^r d_iz^{3^i}=0\}.
  $$

This also follows from the fact that we can view $L$ (or $\overline{L}$) as an $\Bbb{F}_3[\tau]$-module with $\tau$ acting via Frobenius:
$$\tau\cdot z=z^3.$$
In this language $L$ is the cyclic module $\Bbb{F}_3[\tau]/\langle \tau^n-1\rangle$, and the claims follow from general structure theory of modules over a PID.

Anyway, this description lets you to calculate the size of $N$ very quickly for many interesting choices of $k,m$. I have used this many times (though in characteristic two only).

Comment: Thank you! One follow-up question, if you don't mind: Say we pick two distinct pairs $k_1,m_1$ and $k_2,m_2$ corresponding to sets $N_1$ and $N_2$. Is it true that $N_1 \cap N_2 \subseteq \mathbb{F}_3$?

Comment: @user80108 Not necessarily. If the polynomials $1+\tau^{k_1}+\tau^{m_1}$ and $1+\tau^{k_2}+\tau^{m_2}$ have common divisors other than the obvious $\tau-1$, (and that is also a divisor of $\tau^m-1$, then the intersection will be larger. For example 
$$1+\tau+\tau^2\mid 1+\tau^4+\tau^8,$$ so their gcd is $1+\tau+\tau^2=(1-\tau)^2$ that is also a factor of $(1-\tau^n)$. So in this case the intersection would have nine elements.

Comment: We can actually see that in that example case the elements $\beta$ of $\Bbb{F}_{27}$ that have trace zero satisfy both
$$\beta+\beta^3+\beta^9=0$$ and
$$\beta+\beta^{3^4}+\beta^{3^8}=0.$$
This is almost trivial because when $\beta\in\Bbb{F}_{27}$ we have
$$\beta^{3^4}=\beta^3\quad\text{and}\quad\beta^{3^8}=\beta^{3^2}.$$ Probably we can also find more interesting examples.

Comment: Argh, of course. Hmm...what if we restricted ourselves to elements of $\mathbb{F}_{3^n}$ modulo all proper subfields? So, is $N_1 \cap N_2 \subseteq \mathbb{F}_{3^d}$ where $\mathbb{F}_{3^d}$ is some proper subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{3^n}$?

Comment: @user80108 I don't see the answer to that right away. We have $N_1\cap N_2\subseteq \Bbb{F}_{3^d}$ iff 
$$\gcd(1+\tau^{k_1}+\tau^{m_1},1+\tau^{k_2}+\tau^{m_2},1-\tau^n)\mid 1-\tau^d.$$ I'm not sure whether that always happens. With more general polynomials probably it won't, but here we have trinomials with all coefficients equal to one, which may have some consequences (or may not). I'm in the dark at the moment :-(

Comment: (Still thinking about this...) I ran some SAGE code and found that for small $n$, the maximum size of $N$ is $3^{2n/3}$ which occurs when we have $$N = \{ \beta \in \mathbb{F}_{3^n} : \beta+\beta^{3^{n/3}}+\beta^{3^{2n/3}} = 0 \}.$$ I also found that for any other combinations of $m,k$, the elements in $N$ are always contained in some proper subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{3^n}$. I'm not sure if this is suggestive of anything, or if there is way to formalize this logic though.

Comment: Yeah. It's clear that that is the maximum size $N$. But then you need $k_1=k_2=n/3$ and $m_1=m_2=2n/3$ I think?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of just considering one such set $N$. I wonder if it's possible to prove that, given any other set $N_i$ with arbitrary choices of $k_i$ and $m_i$ which is not equal to $N_{max}$ (where $N_{max}$ has $k=n/3$ and $m=2n/3$), all elements of $N_i$ are contained in some proper subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{3^n}$.